# Can we stop ongoing Server process made by http post request in Node.js before sending a response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, request

I have made an application in which i make Ajax call to node server, but the problem is that, if user redirects to another page then also server continues to process the request made by Ajax call and after completing that request, it starts processing the new redirect request.

I am using express as a framework,i don't want to know about client side abort functions, all i need to do is stop server side processing of request made by Ajax call, and instantly start processing for the new request.

Comment: I'm not much of a Node.js guru myself but from what I know about HTTP protocol, it is impossible for the server to know whether a client is still around after making a request. So no, you cannot cancel an ongoing task. However more importantly, your server seems to be handling requests sequentially(i.e. waiting for one to complete before starting another), which is totally unacceptable for a web server as they are supposed to be parallel. I think you should post that specifically as a Node.js question.

Answer (score 0):

> all i need to do is stop server side processing of request made by Ajax call, and instantly start processing for the new request.

If your server is not already processing new requests whether the old request is still processed or not, then you have a bigger problem that cannot be solved just by cancelling the requests that are not needed any more.

Your server should always process new requests no matter if the old ones are still processed or not. To make sure it does you need to make sure to never use any blocking call in your handlers. No functions like `fs.readfileSync` (or anything with Sync in the name), no long running `for` or `while` loops (unless they are in `async function` and don't block the event loop) etc.

When you don't block on old requests before you handle the new ones, you will not have the problem that you describe in your question in which you ask about a specific solution instead of the problem, and the solution you ask about has two issues: it wouldn't solve the problem anyway and it would be impossible to implement.

Comment: i have used for loops in my code but i am not having any loops or waiting process in my server.js, then what could be the technical reason for node to not accept a new request.